# grep multiple strings on multiple file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I have multiple sql files and I want to search those sql file names  on shell script on some path. Can you please help me with the grep command.. And I want to display the sql and shell file name side by side.

e.g:

Path: root/dbjobs (here all the shell files are placed)

Shell 1 contains sql file name sql1,sql2.
After grepping it should display like :

```
Shell1 sql1,sql2
Shell2 sql1,sql3
```

Please help me with the grep command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use `grep '<PATTERN>' . -r`, which tells grep to search the current directory recursively for `<PATTERN>` in **every** file.

#### OR

use `grep '<PATTERN>' <FILES>`, which will tell grep to search the `<FILES>` for `<PATTERN>`.

See `man grep` for more details.